# Using Laravel 4's Input class outside the framework

Tags: php, input, laravel, components, laravel-4

I like the way Laravel 4 handles the input, and how you can get the value via Input::get() no matter if its sent by get, post or whatever.

I'm working on a project that does not use Laravel as the framework, but it will be great if i can use the Input class.

Can anyone help me how can this be done?

Answer (score 12):

Input is, in fact, the Request class. You can require it using Composer:

```
composer require "illuminate/http" "4.x"
```

Require Composer `autoload.php` in your project:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

And use it:

```
$input = Illuminate\Http\Request::createFromGlobals();
var_dump($input->all());
```

Comment: `$request = new Illuminate\Http\Request();
var_dump($request->all());`

returns 

`array (size=0)
  empty`

Comment: I also tried that way, but now i'm getting an error: Method 'all' not found in class Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request

Comment: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Http\Request::createFromBase()

Comment: Strange. This is what I see: http://puu.sh/5m9Sk.png, doing this: http://puu.sh/5m9Tr.png.

Comment: Does anyone know how I can filter something like "<script>alert('hi')</script>"? The js executes when I print the POST values.