# Laravel 4's Input class filtering outside the framework

Tags: php, symfony, input, laravel

My question originates from this post: [Using Laravel 4's Input class outside the framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20051251/using-laravel-4s-input-class-outside-the-framework)

At the moment, when I post some JS, the JS is executed when I print the input to the screen.

Right now I use:

```
$post = Input::createFromGlobals();
```

I would like to know how I can filter the user input. Is this something I have to do manually, or with some other class?

Comment: While I don't know the answer to your question, I should mention that the ``createFromGlobals`` method actually comes from ``Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request`` and not from Laravel in itself. I've added a tag to reflect this. Hope you get the answer from somebody!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to do this manually.
Laravel support helpers provides function `e` which will run the input through `htmlentities` and escape html tags.

If you dont want to use illuminate/support package then you can manually send the input through `htmlentities` function.

Here is the method from `Illuminate/Support` `helper.php` file:

```
function e($value)
{
    return htmlentities($value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', false);
}
```